# Capturing PySpark logging

Tags: python-2.7, logging, pyspark

I am trying to setup a decent logging configuration in PySpark. I have a YAML configuration file which setups different loghandlers. Those handlers consist of the console, a file, and a SQLite DB using the format: `"%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"`.

```
# SETUP LOGGING
with open(cfile, 'rt') as f:
     config = yaml.safe_load(f.read())
logging.config.dictConfig(config)
lg = logging.getLogger("mylog." + self.__name__())
```

So each time I call the `lg.xxxx('message')` everything gets handled quite nicely.

Now I found quite some posts on how to get the log4j from PySpark using `log_handler = sc._jvm.org.apache.log4j`. But now I'm lost on how to add this handler to my existing setup and catch all the messages that happen on the PySpark console and save them to the file and SQLite DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to catch spark jvm logs by python handlers, both these are separated environments. You have two options - to log python messages using log4j from the `sc._jvm` and configure log4j handlers or use separate handlers and merge logs (for example in sqlite) after job finishes.